# -webkit-backface-visibility doesn't work in node-webkit on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, css, css-transforms, node-webkit

I'm using [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) to build a self-contained web app demo, and for some reason, the `-webkit-backface-visibility` CSS3 property doesn't work – but only when I run the app on Windows, not on Mac.

When I say it doesn't work, I mean it's exactly as if the property isn't supported: when I flip an element over on its back, I see it reversed, rather than hidden.

The issue isn't only with my particular code, either, as online demos of `-webkit-backface-visibility` (like [this one](http://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_backface-visibility.cfm)) don't work when I run them in the app on Windows:

[image]

Is this a bug in node-webkit? Is there any way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it sounds like a bug. It might be the same issue that causes WebGL not to be available with specific hardware/driver combinations on Windows:

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Webgl-support-on-windows

> On Windows with some hardware and driver, WebGL won't work until you copy `D3DCompiler_43.dll` and `d3dx9_43.dll` to node-webkit's directory, or install [DirectX 9 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109).
>
> For license reasons we cannot ship those DLLs.

This seems to have fixed a similar problem with `backface-visibility` reported here:
[CSS: backface-visibility and perspective doesn't work](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/631)

> It WORKS! Thanks a lot! I've added two dll files two node-webkit package and it works!

Comment: Thank you! I dropped in the missing DLLs and it fixed the problem immediately.